# Updating Table in asp.net

Tags: c#

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        int Id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Id"]);
        String fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Order/" + fileName));

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ToString());
         con.Open();
        String Update =("Update Order set DesignedImage=@DesignedImage where Id=@Id");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( Update , con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DesignedImage", "Order/" + fileName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", + Id); 
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Label1.Text = "OK"; 
    }
```

I want to update table Order.
this code is giving me syntax error near keyword Order

Comment: By the way, you don't need `(` and `)` for your `Update` string.

Answer (score 3):

`Order` is a [reserved keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in T-SQL. You need use it with square brackets as `[Order]`.

As a best practice, change it to *non*-reserved word.

It would be better to use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

Also don't use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your parameter type ([`SqlDbType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype)) and it's size.

As a last thing, `Open` your connection *just* before you execute your command.

Comment: @Rabie Glad to help.

Comment: hey this is still not updating sql table

Comment: @Rabie What do you mean by not updating? Is this query updates in your sql server? What is your query looks like after you add parameter values?

Comment: i want to insert image in the order table based on order Id . this code is adding image in  the folder Order ,but not updating the sql table

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have Order as your table name since it is reserved keyword on sql queries.
Rename the table and try.

Comment: but i used it with square brackets

Comment: what is in square brackets

Comment: String Update = "Update [Order] set [DesignedImage]=@DesignedImage where [Id]=@Id";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Update, con);

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DesignedImage", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = "Order/" + fileName;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = +id;